# How to get just usernames after @ symbol

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this code which does exactly what im after.
However it only does it for one username, was wondering how I could do it so it gets more than one username from it?

```
$string = 'Tweet @one two @three four';
preg_match("/@(\\w+)/", $string, $matches);
$hash1 = $matches[1];
echo $hash1;
```

$hash1 returns "one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```
$string = 'Tweet @one two @three four';
preg_match_all("/@(\w+)\b/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

- [Demo](https://eval.in/56374)
- [Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/zM3sL7)

Answer (score 1):

Use

`preg_match_all`.

Look here **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)**